# how to diplay message that no result found in uitableview. Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am sending argument in xml feed from search bar to php page.
 now what i want to do is to display no result found in table view if no match found against that argument....
Can any body tell how to do. that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `UISearchDisplayController` it will display the message automatically when zero results are found. It also does a couple of other nice things.